# java.util.NoSuchElementException when mvn remote deploy with wagon

Tags: maven

i want remote deploy with maven
and refer [document](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html)
my pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"         
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multispring</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Parent Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>login</module>
        <module>dao</module>
    </modules>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>ssh-repository</id>
            <url>scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <!-- Enabling the use of SSH -->
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.entry.Main</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my setting.xml is

```
      <server>
          <id>ssh-repository</id>
          <username>root</username>
          <!--<privateKey>/path/to/your/private/key</privateKey> &lt;!&ndash; not needed if using pageant &ndash;&gt;-->
          <configuration>
              <sshExecutable>plink</sshExecutable>
              <scpExecutable>pscp</scpExecutable>
              <!--<sshArgs>other arguments you may need</sshArgs>-->
          </configuration>
          <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
          <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
      </server>
```

when i run mvn deploy
the error is

```
[DEBUG] java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: scp
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: scp
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon(WagonTransporter.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 37 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Multi-Spring Chapter Simple Parent Project ......... FAILURE [  0.487 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] login .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] dao ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.842 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-23T15:47:12+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project simple-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: java.util.NoSuchElementException
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
[ERROR] roleHint: scp
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project simple-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:149)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:265)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Cannot access scp://101.200.161.77/root/project/maven_test/ using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: scp
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:110)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: scp
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon(WagonTransporter.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:115)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 37 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Getting the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Same error here.

Comment: @Vini did you manage to solve?

Comment: @JamMaster did you manage to solve?

Comment: @Daniel managed to solve?